# Limit installations to one or two time per day

Tags: inno-setup

I have Inno Script Create Using IKG (Inno Key generator)
I want Add This Step to My Script
Please Help me.
User can install this setup one or two time per day only.

Eg:

1.get and check date using Internet (because user can change PC date)

2.Save date to registry and a file in program folder ({app}) (date limitation file), like date.txt. Registry and date limitation file must be created after all installation files are copied.

3.Check per date limitation and before installation starts (using registry and date limitation file)

i.limit Over : Msg Cant Install

ii.Limit Not over or registry And Limitation File not Have : Installation Start

Files: [all files link](https://files.fm/u/asxctxuk)

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Why both registry and file?

Comment: What did you try? What step do you have problems with?

Comment: Because difficult  to find both If not user can delete file.

Comment: User can find anything. Relying on information stored on a local machine does not guarantee you anything. You should store this on a server.

Comment: Anyway, again, what step do you have problems with?

Comment: i have low knowledge About coding

Comment: Rather than simply listing a set of requirements - and expecting someone to do it for you - please explain exactly what you have tried and the issue you are experiencing. For further information please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

To implement your test for "too many installations", implement the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).

The best place to increment your "hidden" installation counters is the [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged), when called with `ssPostInstall` argument.

```pascal
[Code]

function TooManyInstallations: Boolean;
begin
  { Here you implement your test }
  Result := False;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if TooManyInstallations then
  begin
    MsgBox('You have installed this too many times', mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure IncrementInstallationCounter;
begin
  { increment your installation counter here }
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    { Installation has beed completed }
    IncrementInstallationCounter;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks For Your help But i cant Build it So If you have the time Please Help me with my script.its build With IKG (Inno) Setup key generator .I edit My question it have all  details

Comment: Why you cannot build it? What specific problem do you have? This is not a code writing service.